# React-native fontFamily: 'Heebo-Medium' does not support italic

Tags: react-native

I was trying to apply `fontFamily: 'Heebo-Medium'` and `fontStyle: 'italic'` onto a nested Text, but the text is not italic unless I take out `fontFamily: 'Heebo-Medium'`.

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Heebo-Medium' }}>
   some text
   <Text style={{ fontStyle: 'italic' }}> some italic text </Text>
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

The font you are using is unlikely to support italic mode.